# What is, and why do I have to restore bitmap hdc or memory dc to the default state when cleaning up?

Tags: winapi, memory-leaks, gdi

When I was looking at BitBlt() examples, I noticed almost all of them were saving the default state of the hdc for bitmaps and then restoring the hdc to the default state using SelectObject() at clean up. Including the source code for Nethack for windows.

Except one of them which wasn't doing that and just cleaning up hdc and bitmaps like how I was doing. I don't see how restoring the hdc to the default state has got something to do with memory leak. Isn't just deleting the hdc enough? Does the hdc loads data or something when you SelectObject() it to a bitmap that you have to restore it to clean it up?

Comment: `SelectObject` transfers ownership. In both directions. The object you select into a device context is owned by the device context. The responsibility for the object selected out of a device context is handed to you. That's how device contexts were designed, decades ago. Decades later and boat loads of bad code that forced the OS into implementing ungodly compatibility fixes leave you with next to no sane options for violating the contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @IInspectable said, you don't HAVE to restore the DC; you only have to "un-select" GDI object that you've allocated from that DC. Otherwise, you can't delete an object that is currently selected into any `DC`.

The `SelectObject()` API conveniently returns to you a previously selected object, so you can just re-select it when you are done with that `DC`.

Also, to clarify, those issues cause resource leaks (non memory leak). That can be worse, since the resources have a pretty low limits (like 10,000 handles, IIRC).